# Auth Forgot Password issue in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel's auth functionality. It's working fine except Forgot Password. I am trying to override following on **ForgotPasswordController**.

```
public function showLinkRequestForm()
{
    return view('admin.forgot');
}
```

It loads the form view for reset password and URL as follows:

```
$this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
```

But when pressing submit button putting email address it shows following errors:

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required

For your kind information, I didn't make any change without DB connection at **.env** file.

How can I send a reset link to the email address?

I hope someone will be able to help me with this.

Comment: Code is correct you need to have a look on your SMTP or Email credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using mailgun by any chance, if so that is your problem? You need to authorize your mailgun account by adding a card. Alternatively, you can add individual emails to the allowed list however you won't know the emails in advance, so just authorize your mailgun and all will be well.